# Ingresar datos de tabla html con php a mysql ¿ Es posible con Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

no sé si esto ha sido resuelto.. sin embargo, hago la pregunta otra vez porque no he logrado poder solucionarlo. Tengo esta tabla que se acumula a medida que quiero añadir datos. Como pueden ver a medida que quiero ingreso datos en el input y el select y le doy añadir, se van formando filas.

```js
var names=document.getElementsByName('datosinternos[]');

function RemoveRow(){
  var table = document.getElementById("tble1");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  //console.log(rowCount);
  
  if(rowCount <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado');
  else
    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
}

function InsertRow()
{
var TableRow="<tr></tr>";
    for(key=0; key < names.length; key++) {
        var combo = document.getElementsByName('datosinternos[]')[1]; 
        var selected = (key==1)? combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text : 
names[key].value; 
        TableRow = TableRow.substring(0,TableRow.length-5) + "<td>" + 
 selected + "</td>" + TableRow.substring(TableRow.length-5);
     }
var TrElement = document.createElement("tr");
    TrElement.innerHTML = TableRow;
    document.getElementById("tble1").appendChild(TrElement);
}
```

```html
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
   <form id="ingresar_datos">
   

 <div class=form-row>
    <div class="col">
    <h6>TEXTO EN COLUMNA 1</h6> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese texto" class="input form-control 
    form-control-sm datepicker" name="datosinternos[]">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    <h6>TEXTO EN COLUMNA 2</h6> 
    <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="datosinternos[]">
      <option disabled>Open this select menu</option>
      <option value="1">Uno</option>
      <option value="2">Dos</option>
      <option value="3">Tres</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col">
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' 
    onclick="InsertRow()">Añadir</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' 
    onclick="RemoveRow()" >Eliminar</button>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-condensed" id="tble1">
    <thead class="thead-primary "><h5 ><strong>MOVIMIENTOS INTERNOS</strong> 
    </h5>
       <tr>                                                                     
          <th>COLUMNA 1</th>                                                 
          <th>COLUMNA 2</th>                                           
       </tr>                                                       
    </thead>
      <tbody>                                                                
        <tr>                                                                
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
 <input type="button" name="btn_enviar" id="btn_enviar" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Lo que necesito finalmente es generar una tabla con determinadas filas (ej: 5 filas) y que una vez esté creada, le de click al boton enviar y se ejecute el ajax para enviar estas determinadas filas a mysql.

Comment: Sí es posible con Ajax, ahora bien tú servidor deberá atender la petición POST que quieres realizar, lo que viene siendo tener un body consensuado en el CLIENT hacia el SERVIDOR

Comment: @joel Garcia Nuño, alguna idea respecto a esto?, con sólo decirme que si no lo soluciona.

Comment: tu pregunta : Ingresar datos de tabla html con php a mysql ¿ Es posible con Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías añadir unos campos ocultos a la tabla con la información que vas añadiendo para luego enviarla con XMLHttpRequest:

**Modificación de la función InsertRow para añadir los campos ocultos:**

```
function InsertRow()
{
    var TableRow="<tr></tr>";
    for (key=0; key < names.length; key++) {
        // Creamos el campo oculto...
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        var combo = document.getElementsByName('datosinternos[]')[1]; 
        var selected = (key==1) ? combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text : names[key].value; 

        // Añadimos los atributos al campo oculto con el valor que se muestra en la tabla...
        input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        input.setAttribute('name', 'column' + key + '[]');
        input.setAttribute('value', selected);

        // Añadimos el campo oculto al código HTML que se añade a la tabla...
        TableRow = TableRow.substring(0,TableRow.length-5) + "<td>" + selected + input.outerHTML + "</td>" + TableRow.substring(TableRow.length-5);
    }
    var TrElement = document.createElement("tr");
    TrElement.innerHTML = TableRow;
    document.getElementById("tble1").appendChild(TrElement);
}
```

**Creación de la función SubmitTable para enviar por POST los datos de los campos ocultos:**

```
function SubmitTable()
{
    // Creamos una instancia de FormData...
    var data = new FormData();

    // Creamos una instancia de XMLHttpRequest...
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Obtenemos los campos ocultos creados y los recorremos guardándolos en dos variables llamadas column0 y column1 que serán enviadas por POST al fichero PHP...
    var column0 = document.getElementsByName('column0[]');
    var column1 = document.getElementsByName('column1[]');

    for (i=0; i < column0.length; i++) {
        data.append('column0[]', column0[i].value);
    }

    for (i=0; i < column1.length; i++) {
        data.append('column1[]', column1[i].value);
    }

    xhttp.open('POST', 'insertar_datos.php', true);
    xhttp.send(data); 
}
```

Con estos dos cambios, solamente quedaría llamar a la función SubmitTable cuando se haga clic en el botón 'Enviar':

```
<input type="button" name="btn_enviar" id="btn_enviar" value="Enviar" onclick="SubmitTable()">
```

Y así, ya tendrías acceso en un fichero PHP (en el ejemplo se llama 'insertar_datos.php', podrías utilizar otro nombre o una URL) a los datos creados dinámicamente ('columna0' y 'columna1').

Comment: Hola o1dskoo1, voy a revisar tu código y te comento

Comment: ¡Suerte con ese código! :)